# What should be the expected value of SD,Throughput,Median,Error percent in Jmeter test plan

Tags: performance, jmeter, test-plan

I have created a test plan in Jmeter and ran it for 10 users, it has run successfully without any error, as in the below screenshot of the listeners which I have added in my test plan.

[image]

[image]

In the above listeners, how may I come to know that the values of these fields Standard Deviation, Throughput, Median, Error% calculated as expected Or is there any ideal/expected/benchmark values of the above fields through which I compare and found that my test plan work as standard. Moreover how may I able to explain that the performance of my test plan is fine/good/better or best

Please suggest me thanks

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you don't really understand what you're doing so I would recommend starting with i.e. [Performance Testing Guidance for Web Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/dajung/ebook-pnp-performance-testing-guidance-for-web-applications) e-book.

---

With regards to the "values" - we have no any idea whether the "values" match your expectations. There are no any reference "values", normally your project should have [non-functional requirements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-functional_requirement) or [SLAs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-level_agreement) which should define maximum response time or minimum number of hits per unit of time.

Check out [JMeter Glossary](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html) to learn what the "values" mean.

---

If you don't have NFRs or SLAs defined you still can perform a [stress test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_testing_(software)) like:

1. Make sure that [your JMeter test behaves like a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser), at least I fail to see:

   - [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager)
   - [HTTP Cache Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager)
   - [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager)
2. You should be running your test in [command-line non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui)
3. Start with 1 virtual user and gradually increase the load until

   - you see the [saturation point](http://hd-performance.blogspot.com/2010/05/saturation-point.html)
   - you start seeing performance degradation

This way you will be able to state what is the maximum number of users you system can support without issues